# Determine possible equations of line $r$, given $PA \cdot PB=17$

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Consider a line $r$ that passes through the point $P(2, 3)$. The line $r$ intersects the curve $x^2-2xy-y^2=0$ at points $A$ and $B$. Knowing that the geometric locus defined by the curve is determined by two perpendicular lines, determine the possible equations of line $r$, given that $PA \cdot PB=17$.

**Solution:**
Is there any other way to solve the problem more easily, using knowledge of analytic geometry with a vectorial approach? Or calculus...? Below is the procedure that would be very effective...

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \text { Coordinates of } A \text { : } \\
& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
y=(\sqrt{2}-1) x \\
y=m x-2 m+3
\end{array}\right.
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
x=\frac{3-2 m}{\sqrt{2}-1-m} \text { e } y=\frac{3 \sqrt{2}-3-2 m \sqrt{2}+2 m}{\sqrt{2}-1-m}
$$
Coordinates of $B$ :
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \left\{\begin{array}{l}
y=-(\sqrt{2}+1) x \\
y=m x-2 m+3
\end{array}\right. \\
& x=\frac{2 m-3}{\sqrt{2}+1+m} \text { e } y=\frac{3 \sqrt{2}+3-2 m \sqrt{2}-2 m}{\sqrt{2}+1+m}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sqrt{\left(\frac{3-2 m}{\sqrt{2}-1-m}-2\right)^2+\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{2}-3-2 m \sqrt{2}+2 m}{\sqrt{2}-1-m}-3\right)^2} \sqrt{\left(\frac{2 m-3}{\sqrt{2}+1+m}-2\right)^2+\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{2}+3-2 m \sqrt{2}-2 m}{\sqrt{2}+1+m}-3\right)^2}=17 \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems involving sum or products of two or more lengths are usually tackled in analytic geometry via parametric coordinates.

Recall a line inclined at $\theta$ to positive $x$ axis and passing through $P=(2,3)$ has [parametric form](https://doubleroot.in/lessons/straight-line/parametric-form/) $(2+r\cos \theta, 3+r\sin \theta)$ where $r$ is signed distance. Putting these coordinates in the curve equation $x^2-2xy-y^2=0$, gives
$$r^2(\cos 2\theta-\sin 2\theta)-2r(\cos\theta + 5\sin \theta)-17=0$$
which is a quadratic in $r$ with roots $|PA|, |PB|$ (signed). Product of roots is
$$|PA|\cdot |PB|=\frac{-17}{\cos 2\theta - \sin 2\theta}=\pm \,17 \quad \text{(given)}$$
$$\cos 2\theta - \sin 2\theta = \pm 1 \; \Rightarrow \; \theta = 0^\circ, 45^\circ, 90^\circ, 135^\circ $$
Hence four lines are obtained in total
$$y=3 \quad \text{or} \quad y=x+1 \quad \text{or} \quad x=2 \quad \text{or}\quad x+y=5$$

Verification for two of these lines to satisfy $PA\cdot PB=17$ in Geogebra :

[image]

Comment: I have never seen this parameterized form... could you give me suggestions for websites and materials that discuss about it?

Comment: There are also the lines y=3, x=2. How to arrive at these solutions?

Comment: @AssandraLakal The trigonometric equation had two more solutions, I added. I have put link for [parametric form](https://doubleroot.in/lessons/straight-line/parametric-form/) also. It comes from simple trigonometry, there is theory + app on linked page, you can change value of $r$ to see how it generates every point of a line at a fixed angle $\theta$.

Comment: @AssandraLakal If you have any more doubts, feel free to ask!